# OpenProcess: ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED despite PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-4.0, pinvoke

I'm trying to access a different user's process's image path. (I'm trying to figure out if the process that's currently running is already also being run by a different user.)

Starting with Vista, .NET's `System.Diagnostics.Process.MainModule` property will fail without UAC. Instead, Win32 suggests first using `OpenProcess` with the `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` flag to get a handle, then `QueryFullProcessImageName`. However, this fails unless the process is my own, or I first elevate my process. Calling `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` then gives me `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

My understanding is the whole point of 'query limited information' is I *shouldn't* have to elevate.

Here's how I've implemented it:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [Flags]
    public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        QueryLimitedInformation = 0x1000
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hprocess, int dwFlags,
                                                         StringBuilder lpExeName, out int size);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess,
                                             bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    public static string GetMainModulePath(this Process process)
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
            return process.MainModule.FileName;

        var buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);

        IntPtr hprocess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryLimitedInformation, false, process.Id);

        if (hprocess != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            try
            {
                int size = buffer.Capacity;
                if (QueryFullProcessImageName(hprocess, 0, buffer, out size))
                    return buffer.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hprocess);
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

I then simply call it like:

```
        foreach (var item in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
        {
            item.GetMainModulePath();
        }
```

Is this not supported at all?

Comment: Note that I'm *not* trying to access system processes. These are simple user-level GUI apps.

Answer (score 1):

You, as a standard user,  don't have rights to look at this information for another user's process. This is how the security model is designed and the system is working as expected.

If you wish to enforce a single instance of your program that is usually done using a named mutex. That topic has been covered here many times before and I won't reproduce what others have already said on this subject.

Comment: In that case, how can I tell, at all, if my process is already being run?

Comment: It's normally done using a named mutex. You approach won't work anyway because of the race condition when two process start at the same time.